# Bash - Redirection with wildcards

Tags: bash

I'm testing to do redirection with wildcards. Something like:

```
./TEST* < ./INPUT* > OUTPUT
```

Anyone have any recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to iterate over files that match a pattern? Pick one file that matches the pattern?

Comment: There is a program called TEST* that has to get various redirection into into called INPUT*, but the thing is there are many TEST programs and they all have a different number, e.g. TEST678. What I'm trying to do is push all the random INPUT files into all the all TEST programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a program called TEST* that has to get various redirection into into called INPUT*, but the thing is there are many TEST programs and they all have a different number, e.g. TEST678. What I'm trying to do is push all the random INPUT files into all the all TEST programs.

You can write:

```
for program in TEST*            # e.g., program == 'TEST678'
do
  suffix="${program#TEST}"      # e.g., suffix == '678'
  input="INPUT$suffix"          # e.g., input == 'INPUT678'
  "./$program" < "$input"       # e.g., run './TEST678 < INPUT678'
done > OUTPUT
```

Comment: +1 if the programs and input files need to be matched up one-to-one like this.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have the following 5 files: `TEST1`, `TEST1`, `INPUT1`, `INPUT2`, and `OUTPUT`. The command line

```
./TEST* < ./INPUT* > OUTPUT
```

will expand to

```
./TEST1 ./TEST2 < ./INPUT1 ./INPUT2 > OUTPUT.
```

In other words, you will run the command `./TEST1` with 2 arguments (`./TEST2`, `./INPUT2`), with its input redirected from `./INPUT1` and its output redirected to `OUTPUT`.

To address what you are probably trying to do, you can only specify a single file using input redirection. To send input to `TEST` from both of the `INPUT*` files, you would need to use something like the following, using process substitution:

```
./TEST1 < <(cat ./INPUT*) > OUTPUT
```

---

To run each of the programs that matches `TEST*` on all the input files that match `INPUT*`, use the following loop. It collects the output of all the commands and puts them into a single file `OUTPUT`.

```
for test in ./TEST*; do
    cat ./INPUT* | $test
done > OUTPUT
```

Comment: Wow that makes a lot more sense now. How would you add wildcards to the TEST? Would you do (cat ./TEST*)?

Answer (score 0):

```
for test in ./TEST*; do
 for inp in ./INPUT*; do
   $test < $inp >> OUTPUT
 done
done
```

Comment: Image `$test` is `sort`; this will give a different result than `cat ./INPUT* | sort`.